# Dynamic enum-like list during debug

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to make something like this in C#?

```
// Pseudo-code   
enum Tables{}

sql.createTable("Tablename")
Tables.Add("Tablename");

sql.createTable("Tablename2")
Tables.Add("Tablename2");


//and then select the added Tablename from the property list
// like it works with an regular enum list
Tables.Tablename
Tables.Tablename2
```

Comment: No but you may use a dictionary.

Comment: @Adriano Maybe if you elaborate on this a bit more (code samples) and write it as an answer, you will get credited for your upvotes...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar given just a hint because I'm pretty lazy in this moment, I'd feel happy to upvote anyone would elaborate that to become an answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a sample of `Adrianos` idea:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tables = new Dictionary<string, string>();

sql.createTable("Tablename");
tables["Tablename"] = "Tablename";

sql.createTable("Tablename2");
tables["Tablename2"] = "Tablename2";
```

Then, later on, you could do this:

```
sql.insertIntoTable(tables["Tablename"], value1, ...);
```

Why use a dictionary with both key an value of the same name? So that you can access the table name by its name. If you had only a list, you would only be able to access the table names by index.

This way, you can write `tables["Tablename"]` and access the table's name by its name... oO

One question remains: Why? If you know the table names in advance, what would be the problem in just hardcoding that name in further calls?

Comment: thanks thorsten. i will try it tomorrow. i´m writing a class with sql functions and i thought it would be nice that the coder can pick a table or column(if we elaborate the technique) out of a list but during the coding. like enum. you type like tables and in the popup-property-list you can select the table which is not really there but theoretical because it will be created before it will be added to that list. i´m a lazy one, too. can you follow me?